# Problems with Modal in Rails opening the same object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3, bootstrap-modal

I'm maintaining an older Rails 3.2.22 app and I'm trying to add a modal to pop up with a simple form to add a note.

Here is my view (cut down for readability)

```
<% @assigned.each do |call| %>
          <%= link_to "Notes", '#ajax-modal', data: { toggle: "modal", target: "#note-modal" }, class: 'btn btn-small btn-inverse' %>
        <%= render 'layouts/note_modal', :call => call %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my modal app/views/layouts/_note_modal.html.erb

```
    <div id="note-modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3 class="modal-title"><%= call.incident_number %> Notes</h3>
      </div>
      <div class='modal-body'>
        <div class="modal-body-content">       

  <%= form_for(@note, url: call_note_calls_path, html: {class: "form-inline"}) do |f| %>
                   <%= f.text_field :message, :maxlength => 255 %>
                   <%= f.hidden_field :call_id, value: call.id %>
                   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
                  <%= f.button "Add Note", class: 'btn btn-info btn-small', data: {disable_with: "<i class='icon-spinner'></i>Posting..."} %>
                  <% end %></div>
    <div class="ajax-loader">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class='modal-footer'>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I load the page and there are several calls I click on the notes link, the partial renders in a modal and I can submit a note.  The problem is if I have 10 calls on the screen no matter which notes link I click on it adds a note to the first call on the screen.

Am I passing locals incorrectly?  I know this code is inside of the block so it should pull the call object and pass it as a local to the partial in the modal but it's not.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you render the modal each time for a note but they all have the same id. So you are always opening the first modal. Actually IMHO you just need to render the modal **once** and pass the note_id via an data attribute on the link which triggers the modal. So basically configure the modal via the caller.

Comment: I think you are right because I'm rendering the partial inside of the loops it's getting the same ID.  If I move the render partial outside of the loop I get undefined local variable `call`.  Can you provide an example on how to set the id in the data attributes?

Comment: Sorry, my backend skills are better than my front end so I'm fumbling a bit with this one.

Comment: you now solved it with having n modals with n unique ids, I simply proposed to have one modal which picks up the needed note_id as soon as it is called, that's how I resolved same problem a while ago, but as long as your solution is working ;) (still gave the hint to the unique modal id though I guess ^^)

Comment: Of course, I went ahead and marked your answer since it was on the the right path. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out on my own and still render the partial within the loop by calling an index as part of the target ID for the modal.  Working code below.

```
<% @assigned.each_with_index do |call, index| %>
  <%= link_to "Notes", '#note-modal', data: {toggle: "modal", target: "#note-modal#{index}" }, class: 'btn btn-small btn-inverse' %>
    <%= render 'layouts/note_modal', call: call, index: index %>
 <% end %>

<div id="note-modal<%= index %>" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1">
  <div class='modal-header'>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3 class="modal-title"><%= call.incident_number %> Notes</h3>
  </div>
  <div class='modal-body'>
    <div class="modal-body-content">
      <%= form_for(@note, url: call_note_calls_path, html: {class: "form-inline"}) do |f| %>
               <%= f.text_field :message, :maxlength => 255 %>
               <%= f.hidden_field :call_id, value: call.id %>
               <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
              <%= f.button "Add Note", class: 'btn btn-info btn-small', data: {disable_with: "<i class='icon-spinner'></i>Posting..."} %>
              <% end %></div>
    <% call.notes.each do |n| %>
    <li><%= n.message %> added by <%= n.user.username %></li>
    <% end %>
    <div class="ajax-loader">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class='modal-footer'>
    <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```